# Cypher conditions on all nodes in collection behaving incorrectly?

Tags: collections, path, cypher, conditional-statements, nodes

I have this database:

```
CREATE (A:A {name:"A"})-[:R]->(B:B {name:"B"})-[:R]->(C:B {name:"C"})-[:R]->(D:A {name:"D"})-[:R]->(E:A {name:"E"})
```

This query

```
MATCH p = (:A)-[*]->(:B) WITH NODES(p)[1..] AS p_nodes RETURN p_nodes
```

returns edge `(B)-->(C)`. And `B` and `C` have both label `B`. Why then does this query

```
MATCH p = (:A)-[*]->(:B) WITH NODES(p)[1..] AS p_nodes

WHERE ALL(x IN p_nodes[0..] WHERE LABELS(x) = "B") RETURN p_nodes
```

return nothing (no rows)? The only thing it does is make sure that `p_nodes` contains `B` labeled nodes only. And as the first query showed it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labels(x)` function will return a collection of strings, not a string. This is because nodes can have multiple labels.

So instead of comparing `labels(x) = "B"` use the `IN` operator `"B" in labels(x)`:

```
MATCH p =(:A)-[*]->(:B)
WITH NODES(p)[1..] AS p_nodes
WHERE ALL (x IN p_nodes[0..] 
    WHERE "B" IN LABELS(x))
RETURN p_nodes
```